# Flutter : how to check connectivity using firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, connectivity

How to check connectivity and show images only when there is an internet connection else show circular progress indicator. In my following code indicator is just appearing only for a second even when there is not an internet connection.

```
class About extends StatelessWidget {   
    List<Image> _listOfImages = <Image>[];
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(    
      body:     ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 5,
                top: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 5,
                right: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 5),
            child: Material(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 80,
                height: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 80,
                
                child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: Firestore.instance.collection('About').snapshots(),
   
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.data.documents.length == 0){
                    return Center(
                        child: 
                                CircularProgressIndicator()
                      );                   
                  }
                   else {
                   return ListView.builder(
                      
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          _listOfImages = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this package out:

- [Connectivity Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity)

It is a great package/library which does this job for you. To make use of that, just import and do like this the below example:

```
      Future<bool> check() async {
        var connResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
        if (connResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
          return true;
        } else if (connResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
```

> Note that on Android, this does not guarantee connection to Internet. For instance, the app might have wifi access but it might be a VPN or a hotel WiFi with no access.

**Alternate Usage**

The main idea is to check whether the link can be opened or not, we're using `google.com` in this case. You can then, return your `boolean` to do your stuffs based upon that.

```
import 'dart:io'

bool isConnected = false;
// use try-catch to do this operation, so that to get the control over this 
// operation better
try{
  final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
  if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
    // do the operation for connected, or change the bool to True for connected
    setState(() => isConnected = true);
  }
} on SocketException catch (_) {
   setState(() => isConnected = false);
}
```

To know more the `InternetAddress`, follow this: [InternetAddress Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/InternetAddress-class.html).

Comment: @Aju You can add it anywhere, but adding it in your `initState()` would be better. From there you can get your `connection status` via some `bool value`. Then in your place where you are calling the API, check the bool value, and then perform operation. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand.Can you relate it with my code from above?

Comment: What do you want to happen when the internet is not there @Aju?

Comment: if (snapshot.data.documents.length == 0){
                    return Center(
                        child: 
                                CircularProgressIndicator()  // I want to check whether there is connection or not, if there is no connection i want to print progress indicator //
                      );                   
                  }
                   else {
                   return ListView.builder                // else i want to print this widget

Comment: @Aju But you're already showing up your `circularProgressBarIndicator` in your `snapshot.data.lenght == 0`, aren't you?  Better show some message, or a pop up to turn their internet connection. Like other app does, when no connection, they show some broken message, with a button to refresh.

Comment: Indicator in not appearing when the is no connection , it's just showing blank

Comment: And when you have Internet connection, then it shows up, right @Aju?

Comment: Yes. But when there is no connection the indicator just appear for a second and it dissapears

Comment: The reason, I guess @Aju, it somehow, gets `an empty string: ""`, and it passes to your list, which shows nothing but a blank screen. Let us figure something out

Comment: Can you help me to combine my code and this connectivity code.

Comment: Is this related to Cloud Firestore?